# .Net 6.0 Web SDK class library creation

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, class-library

We've got a class library we've built internally that, among other things, exposes some HTTP clients specifically for authorizing other requests (acquiring/refreshing tokens, etc.). Until now, it has been built as `netstandard2.1`, and we've been able to keep the dependencies up-to-date with no issues.

We recently ported an additional auth client type down from a consuming application into this library. The existing implementation had the client being used by an `IAsyncActionFilter` implementation so that it could be added as an attribute on a method:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class OpaAuthAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public OpaAuthAttribute(string permission) : base(typeof(OpaAuthActionFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { permission };
    }
}
```

This works, but staying with the `netstandard2.1` TFM has left us dependent on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` v2.2.0. That's really not a great go-forward path, since that project has already been archived for 4 years, and as-published it depends on several library versions that have known security vulnerabilities:
[image: Snyk scan results].

So, I'm trying to figure out the path to an upgradeable implementation, and that means moving to `net6.0`. I'm able to get all of the dependencies in place by changing this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    ...
```

to this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">   <!-- Changed -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>   <!-- Changed -->
    ...
```

But I still get the following error in the build output:

```
Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
```

Is it possible to create a class library that consumes the latest versions of the ASP.Net MVC SDK? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the answer was really trivial: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` projects apparently default to

```xml
<OutputType>exe</OutputType>
```

So even though [the default `OutputType` value for MSBuild is `Library`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=OutputType,Windows%2Dbased%20program), because I was using the Web SDK I had to update my .csproj file to explicitly state that I wanted a class library:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>library</OutputType>
    ...
```